# How do I inverse sort a dictionary that has sets as values?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, set

So I have the dictionary below:

```
adict = {1: set(['a', 'b']), 2: set(['b', 'c'])}
```

How do I inverse the dictionary so when I print inv_dict, I get the following output:

```
inv_dict = {'a': set([1]), 'b': set([1, 2]), 'c': set([2])}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the dictionary, building a new:

```
inverse = {}
for key, values in adict.items():
    for value in values:
        inverse.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
```

Demo:

```
>>> adict = {1: set(['a', 'b']), 2: set(['b', 'c'])}
>>> inverse = {}
>>> for key, values in adict.items():
...     for value in values:
...         inverse.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
...
>>> inverse
{'a': set([1]), 'c': set([2]), 'b': set([1, 2])}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!